# How would I make a custom Powershell Command?

Tags: powershell

I would like to make a powershell command, such as `startcode` that should go to a different folder, and run a python file. I want this command to be accessible from ANY directory that my powershell terminal is in. I made a powershell program with this so far:

```
function startcode() {
  cd ~
  cd Blah blah blah
  echo 'Starting!!'
  python hello.py
}
```

How would I make the command `startcode` available everywhere?

Comment: Put it in your `$profile`, or [create a module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/module/how-to-write-a-powershell-script-module)

Comment: I'll try that, thanks!

Comment: Remember that there are separate profiles for the Powershell clients ISE and Console

Comment: Like Mathias said: put the function in your [profile](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/05/21/understanding-the-six-powershell-profiles.aspx).

Comment: I am missing the Powershell folder in my documents

Comment: Create the directory, then put the profile script in it.

Comment: What do I name the folder? Can I just name it powershell?

Comment: No; the directory has to be named exactly as in the `$PROFILE` variable.